# VBA: SendKeys "^c" seems to be copying to a different clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that copies a code from excel and pastes it into and application. If the code succeeds the cursor in the application automatically highlights text `0`. I then have the keyboard do "ctrl-c", which copies it correctly in the fact that I can paste `0` anywhere I choose by manually using my keyboard. But within the macro, using the paste function or directly accessing the clipboard doesn't give back this value, but other values copied in the macro at a prior line. Surprisingly enough, if I run my macro with a stop (big red dot) in the middle, after the "ctrl-c" command, it works fine, but then I have to run it in two steps.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub CopyUPCtoRMS()
Dim UPC As String
Dim SomeInRMS As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets(1)
i = 2

'While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5))
    UPC = sht.Cells(i, 5).Copy
    AppActivate "Retek - prd"
    SendKeys "%r" & "{tab}{tab}{tab}", True 'reset the form
    SendKeys "^v" & "{ENTER}", True 'paste UPC into retek
    SendKeys "^c", True 'Copies '0' to a global clipboard.
    '**I put a stop here and run the code in 2 portions as "Microsoft Visual Basic" lets you, and it works, but in two parts... 
    sht.Range("F10").Value = ClipBoard_GetText '<--- Pastes the UPC, not '0'
'Wend
End Sub
```

I've tried replacing the SendKeys with a function that does something similar to the same results (I can post that code if needed), to no avail. Anyway, that's all I can think of for now, it took several hours to figure out what was even wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an automation program like it seems you've done and have had similar issues.  I think your last SendKeys call and the Clipboard_GetText call are happening in a timing where the copy function is not having time to complete before the next call executes.  How I solved this in my application is grabbing the Sleep function from kernel32.dll (there is an article about it here: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-wait-and-sleep-functions/ - have to declare it differently for 64 bit systems) by placing this declaration in a place your code can see it (same module should be fine - all the way at the top prior to any functions or subs):

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

And then after each SendKeys call, you can force your code to pause a bit; since time is in milliseconds, 1000 is one second.  So, for example, you can call

```
Sleep 500
```

and there will be a half second pause between the next line of code being run.  I think this may work for you, because when you put a breakpoint (the red dot), have the code stop, and run it again manually, it works, apparently.  So I think it may be a timing issue that Sleep can help you out with.  If that's the issue, play with the sleep time to keep the operation time to a minimum.  Good luck.